# pg_dump password in python

Tags: python, postgresql, pg-dump

I have a ubuntu remote server say 172.123.342.12. I want to take backup of a postgresql database on my local machine via a python script.

My Script is:

```
def backUp(self):
        Pass = 'fb2024d4'
        os.putenv("PGPASSWORD",Pass)
        dt = datetime.now()
        format = "%Y_%b_%d"
        cur_time = dt.now()
        form_time = cur_time.strftime(format)
        backup_str = "C:\\Bitnami\\odoo-8.0-7\\postgresql\\bin\\pg_dump.exe --format=c -h 172.123.342.12 -p 5432 -d new_db -U bn_openerp > C:\\Users\\n\\Desktop\\Odoo_Backups\\%s.dump" %form_time
        os.system(backup_str)
        print ("Backup Created in Desktop")
        box.showinfo("Information", "Backup Created")

backup()
```

It does nothing. Some help will be appreciated.

EDIT: The Script works on a database on windows as i am using admin account. So it does not asks for password. But When i try to backup a database from remote ubuntu server. It asks for password.
I have tried following solutions:

```
1.) SET PGPASSPASSWORD = C:\foo\bar..\pgpass.conf.
2.) os.putenv("PGPASSWORD","password")
3.) PGPASSWORD='password' pg_dump.exe -h localhost.....
```

No one worked for me.

Comment: you can't run " backup_str = "C:\\Bitnami\\odoo-8.0-7\\postgresql\\bin\\pg_dump.exe" on ubuntu...

Comment: you can save a password in .pgpass file

Comment: i am running it from my local windows machine. i have postgresql installed. so i just need to pass on parameters -h -p -d -U and it will do the rest. thats why i asked how to pass postgres password in windows

Comment: save apassword to pgpass file - read   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-pgpass.html "On Microsoft Windows the file is named %APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf (where %APPDATA% refers to the Application Data subdirectory in the user's profile)." (c)

Comment: can you elaborate a little more. file pgpass.conf was there in directory you said. i edited it and saved a password

Comment: if you saved it in correct format, when you connect to a database it will be automatically consumed

Comment: 172.123.342.12:5432:new_db:bn_openerp:fb2024d4

Comment: I did it the same way. how do i pass it?

Comment: when you call pg_dump, it will pickup the file itself. first tries PGPASSWORD var, then PGPASS, then tries default pgpass. automatically

Comment: Giving me thid error.      pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "new_db" failed: FATAL:  passwor
d authentication failed for user "bn_openerp"

Comment: *:*:*:bn_openerp:fb2024d4 change this way?..

Comment: 172.123.342.12:5432:*:bn_openerp:fb2024d4    i am using this string.

Comment: try all stars but the password

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78884/discussion-between-manish-gupta-and-vao-tsun).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a python script to create a dump file using pg_dump.exe:

```
filename = 'C:/Path/To/File/mydb_dump.sql'
pgDump = 'C:/Program Files/PostgeSQL/9.5/bin/pg_dump'

subprocess.Popen('"{}" -h 127.0.0.1 dbname > "{}"'.format(pgDump, filename), shell=True)
```

### A few things to note:

**I STRONGLY CAUTION AGAINST USING** `shell=True` **!!!**

There is a huge security hazard with possible shell injections as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

I'm not sure if will work with a *remote* Ubuntu server, but I couldn't see why not if all permissions and sharing is setup properly.

I know this is pretty old, but I hope it helps.